# I want to find max value comparing 100 columns with data frame

Tags: apache-spark-sql, hadoop2

I have a dataframe

```
syr | P1    | P2
-----------------
1   | 200   | 300
2   | 500   | 700
3   | 900   | 400
```

I want to create another DataFrame which has max value between `col2` & `col3`. An expected output is like:

```
syr | P1    | P2    | max
-------------------------
1   | 200   | 300   | 300
2   | 500   | 700   | 700
3   | 900   | 400   | 900
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a new UDF function to catch the max value between two column, like:

```
def maxDef(p1: Int, p2: Int): Int = if(p1>p2) p1 else p2
val max = udf[Int, Int, Int](maxDef)
```

And then apply the UDF in a `withColumn()` to define a new Column, like:

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("max", max(df.col("P1"), df.col("P2")))
+---+---+---+---+
|syr| P1| P2|max|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|200|300|300|
|  2|500|700|700|
|  3|900|400|900|
+---+---+---+---+
```

**EDIT: Iterate through columns**

First initialize the `max` Column:

```
df = df.withColumn("max", lit(0))
```

then foreach Column you want (use `filter` function property) compare it with the `max` Column.

```
df.columns.filter(_.startsWith("P")).foreach(col => {
  df = df.withColumn("max", max(df.col("max"), df.col(col)))
})
```

Comment: Thank you for response.. this is working for 2 columns,if I have 100 column how to do it